# Selectbox displays its options above selectbox control when mouse hover on it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-selectbox

When I hover to my select box it display options above the select box control when hover on  it.It should display options below select box as default options displayed.When the option is selected the select box should close but it only close on hover out
the image is attached below.the options are showing above select box and select box is hide behind them

Select GradePrimaryGCSEA Level

css

```
.quick-links__list {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.select_box {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
}
.quick-links__item .select_box .form-control > option {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

 $('select#search_select').hover(function(){
    var count = $(this).children().length;
    $(this).attr('size', count);

},function(){
    $(this).removeAttr('size');

});
```

[image: select box is hide behind the options when hover]

Comment: What does your HTML and CSS look like? Please give us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Edit your question to include both your HTML and CSS. Don't post additional code in comments.

Comment: edited. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: I see no CSS? And also, are you using some PHP-templating engine? Which one? What does the generated output look like?

Comment: just a min. i will give you details